# Two different ways to generate the topology of convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the measure space $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ where $\mu(X) < \infty$. Let $L(X)$ denote the space of measurable functions on $X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Then one way to define the topology of convergence in measure is by defining a seminorm $$\|f\| = \int_{X}\frac{|f|}{1 + |f|}\, d\mu$$ and considering the balls generated by this seminorm. On the other hand another way to generate this topology is by considering the topology generated by the basis
$$B_{\epsilon}(f, r) = \{g \in L(X): \mu(\{x: |f(x) - g(x)| \geq r\}) < \epsilon\}.$$
Are these two topologies equivalent?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but one can show that, $\lim\int_X \frac{f_n}{1+f_n}=0\Leftrightarrow f_n$converges to $0$ in measure